# How to raise an array of numbers to a power with NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

NumPy has `log`, `log2`, and `log10` methods which can perform vectorized log base e / 2 / 10 (respectively). However, for doing the inverse operation (exponentiation), I only see `exp`. Why is there no `exp2` / `exp10` / etc?

I've tried using `np.power(10, nums)`, but it won't let me raise to a negative power. `10 ** nums` does not work either.

Comment: Use `10.0` instead of `10`.

Comment: What is `nums` here? Unless you have an integral type this should be doable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work fine with `10 ** nums` provided you use the `float` dtype. Otherwise it will create an integer array:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int)
>>> 2 ** a
array([0, 1, 2, 4, 8])
>>> 10 ** a
array([   0,    1,   10,  100, 1000])
>>> a = numpy.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
>>> 10 ** a
array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+02,   1.00000000e+03])
```

You can also coerce to `float` by using `10.0` instead of `10`:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int)
>>> 10.0 ** a
array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+02,   1.00000000e+03])
```